# Codeigniter Activerecord WHERE IN AND with multiple checkbox array from ajax

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am able to Pass multiple check box array in jquery to codeigniter controller and var_dump values look like this:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(3) "100" [1]=> string(3) "101" [2]=> string(3) "102"[3]=> string(3) "103" [4]=> string(3) "104" [5]=> string(3) "105" }
```

I would like to pass this array values in Where in Condition Active record.
But When I Checking it display like continuous loop and not stoping execution. Any one Know Please Help

**Model Look Like This**

```
function getListofItems($itemcode,$leaftype,$color)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('itemcode', $itemcode);
  if(is_array($leaftype) && count($leaftype) > 0){
    $this->db->where_in('leaftype', $leaftype);
  }
  if(is_array($color) && count($color) > 0){       
    $this->db->where_in('color', $color);
  }
  $this->db->order_by('flag', 'ASC');
  $query = $this->db->get('tbl_search_list');
  $return =array();
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use $this->db->from("what table dude?");

Comment: Thanks .i've tried that but still not working

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: not showing any error but while checking on checkbox the loading icon does not stops while the query ends. If I remove $this->db->where_in('color', $color); it stops the query

Comment: if you use $this->db->from("table") please remove $this->db->get("table")

Comment: yes i have done that..I think the error is while posting the array values in $color and $leaftype

Comment: I found this line having error ```$this->db->where('itemcode'=>$itemcode);``` , I edited the question. check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one :) i only edit small things

```
function getListofItems($itemcode,$leaftype,$color)
{
  $this->db->select('*')->from("tbl_search_list");
  $this->db->where('itemcode' => $itemcode);

  if(is_array($leaftype) && count($leaftype) > 0)
    $this->db->where_in('leaftype', $leaftype);

  if(is_array($color) && count($color) > 0)
    $this->db->where_in('color', $color);


  $this->db->order_by('flag', 'ASC');

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
     return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: The ```$query``` variable not assigned before executing the ```$query->result()```, so it may produce the error. I edited the answer for that.